# Android how to optimize App for Tablet

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

I've created an app that is designed to work exclusively on tablets.

But in Google Play, it seems to be an phone app and I get optimization tips in Developer Console that I should optimize it for Tablets.

How can I make sure that my app is for tablets?

Comment: have you create a layout for tablets i.e large and xlarge layouts?

Comment: I did that now (layout-large), but it says like before "Customize your layout on tablets."...

Comment: also on the listing make sure you provide images for the tablet screen on your development console on google play

Comment: I did that and it says that my APK file is not developed for tablets but the screenshots are made on tablets.

Comment: I did all that is mentioned here: [Link](http://www.hasmukhbhadani.com/2013/01/how-to-create-application-for-both.html)

Comment: I think google has explained well in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/tablet-app-quality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create layout-sw600 folder and above that should work